# Visualization and setting up the Kneser graph of the number of combinations "a from n by k" in Mathematica

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

I need to visualize the combination "a from n to k" using a graph $KG_{n,k}$ and depict the following:

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph#/media/File:Kneser_graph_KG(5,2).svg]

As we know, the graph structure is determined by the number of vertices and the connection between them (which is described by the adjacency matrix or incidence matrix, etc.).

From the graph tutorial [Graph](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html), I did not see that it was possible to work with matrices, so I had to create this graph manually, but it remained unclear to me how to make it look like this graph from Wikipedia.

Can someone work with me on this and show how this is done?

And the second question: is it possible to use the Mathematica to study its properties?

Comment: That looks awfully like `PetersenGraph[5, 3]`.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Are you trying to construct a specific graph? Are you trying to create a specific visualization of a given graph? What are the precise requirements? The question is not nearly focused enough.

Comment: `kneserGraph[n_, k_] :=
 RelationGraph[
  DisjointQ,
  Subsets[Range[n], {k}]
  ]`

Comment: I am trying to create a specific graph structure and visualize it so that it looks like a graph from Wikipedia.
I do not know what commands to use for this.

Comment: The second command did not work for me. Nothing happens after launch.

Comment: It's a definition, there is no output. You need to use the function that is defined.

Comment: It defines a function, which you're then supposed to evaluate; e.g. `kneserGraph[5, 3]`.

Comment: This is what I got using these commands.
[link](https://ibb.co/N70PgNk)

Comment: There is way too much in this question. I strongly suggest you break it down, and proceed step by step, especially since you're a beginner (you do not seem to be familiar with function definitions). There are different tasks: how to create a Kneser graph? how to lay it out nicely? Here you show a very common layout of the Petersen graph, but it's unclear how to generalize this (the only one I know that can is one of the GraphViz layouts). The vast majority of automated layout methods cannot recover this layout. Then there's the question of how to create custom visualizations for each vertex.

Comment: I agree that this is how the issue needs to be detailed. Do I need to edit a question?

Comment: "This is what I got using these commands" What result would you expect for $K_{5,3}$?

Comment: See the answer to this thread.

Comment: In general, maybe there are options for visualizing combinations of from "a n to k" in addition to Kneser graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[vSF]
vSF[n_, r_: .1, ps_: 15] := Module[{cp = CirclePoints[r/2, n]}, 
    Translate[Function[x, Join[{White, Disk[{0, 0}, r], Gray, AbsolutePointSize[ps]}, 
        MapAt[{Red, #} &, Point /@ cp, List /@ x], 
        MapThread[Text[Style[#, Black], #2] &, {x, cp[[x]]}]]]@#2, #]] &;

subsets = RotateRight @ SortBy[-Subtract @@ # &]@Subsets[Range[5], {2}];

cpoints = CirclePoints[.2, 5];


RelationGraph[DisjointQ, subsets, 
 VertexCoordinates -> Join[5 cpoints, 10 RotateRight@cpoints ], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> vSF[5, .3]]
```

[image]

```
RelationGraph[DisjointQ, Subsets[Range[6], {2}], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> vSF[6, .10, 12], ImageSize -> Large, 
 GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]
```

[image]

```
RelationGraph[DisjointQ, Subsets[Range[6], {3}], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> vSF[6, .1, 12], ImageSize -> Large, 
 GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]
```

[image]

```
RelationGraph[DisjointQ, Subsets[Range[7], {3}], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> vSF[7, .075, 9], ImageSize -> Large, 
 GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is similar to what I wanted to get. And can we use this command to build Kneser's graphs of a different structure, for example, $KG_{8,3}$?

Comment: Your code visualize the graph well, but do not quite correctly display its structure. 

`cp = MapAt[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], #} &, 
     Point /@ CirclePoints[.2, 6], List /@ #] & /@ 
   Subsets[Range[6], {3}];`

`PetersenGraph[6, 3, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> ({White, Disk[#, .35], Gray, 
     AbsolutePointSize[10], Translate[cp[[#2]], #]} &)]`

Is the graph built by this code true?

Comment: @dtn, getting the vertex layout right is the challenge for the general case.

Comment: In general, maybe there are other ways to visualize combinations from "a from n by k" besides Kneser's graphs?

Comment: Why is graph $KG_{6,3}$ so strange? It seems that three lines should come from one node, but why does one come out for some reason?

Comment: @dtn, I don't understand _"three lines should come from one node"_. For any 3-subset `s` of `Range[6]` , the only other 3-subset that has empty intersection with `s` is its complement, no?

Comment: Most likely, you are right. If the question is not appropriate due to a gap in my knowledge. I will try to eliminate it.